# UWP - Authentication Options

Tags: c#, cloud-service, authentication

I have an UWP app (C#) and i want their users have to authenticate in the cloud. Also, I need to enable/disable access to these users arbitrarily.
I' ve tried Azure AD and I get good results but I want to check other alternatives.
Basically, I need:

- let users register to the app with any email
- authenticate users
- authorize access to app

Do you know options to Azure AD?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I've tried Auth0 (https://auth0.com/). 
All authentication activities required are met. Also, you can manage accounts trough Auth0 API Management.
Free version let you authenticate users (you can add 2 social networks) and define attributes to users. 
Email customization is allowed (paid subscription)
Definitely it works fine!

Comment: Thanks for self-answering! Unfortunately, this post does not contain enough information to be considered an answer. Please [read our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) to see if you can incorporate some of these improvements into your answer. Especially missing: where to find Auth0, and how does it meet your requirements?